# How can I add a contact programmatically?

Tags: android, contacts

I use the following code to add a contact :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, ATTACH_VCARD_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But on my Google Nexus the default Android Contact Manager application doesn't return result to my activity

I have the following behaviour:
 1. I call contact manager
 2. Add field name and click "Done"

After that opens other Activity of default Android Contact Manager, and I can leave this activity only if I press back or up button. After that I can't return to my application activity using back stack (back button). I can open my application with Recent Tasks Manager, but then I get resulCode == 0 and intent == null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed source code of standart Contacts application and found Activity which is responsible for creating new contact. There is flag INTENT_KEY_FINISH_ACTIVITY_ON_SAVE_COMPLETED = "finishActivityOnSaveCompleted"; If this flag is true then called setResult(RESULT_OK);

So solution of this problem is

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, ATTACH_VCARD_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: This does not work on 4.4.2 android devices. Does someone know a solution? Please share...